# How to make python 3 scripts execute from .bat file on Windows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, batch-file, execution

Very new to programming even newer to asking on stackoverflow so apologies if badly worded and/or formatted.

I'm using Python 3.7.2 on Windows 10.
I'm trying to make .bat files so I can execute my python code without having to go into IDLE.

My python code is

```
#! python
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('https://killsixbilliondemons.com/')
```

and the .bat file reads

```
@ C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe C:\Users\User\Desktop\Codes\PROGS\mapIt.py
```

When I run it a command prompt window momentarily opens then closes but nothing happens in my browser. What's going wrong?

Comment: If anyone else is experiencing this problem I also needed to close the file paths in the .bat in  double quotes "" so cmd could parse the white space characters

Comment: Also, for clarity, my issue was not that I don't see what happens in the comand prompt that appears but that the code in the .py file didn't seem to be executing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `import webrowser` contains a typo, it should be `import webbrowser`. Fixing that line should fix your issue.

Furthermore, if you want to see the output of a `.bat` file, try running it from a pre-made `cmd` prompt by hitting `windows + r`, entering `cmd` in the prompt that appears, going to the directory the `.bat` file is in through the `cd <FULLPATH>` command and calling it through `<NAMEOFBATFILE>.bat`.

Answer (score 2):

First, if that's all your code, don't use python at all and just use `start "" https://killsixbilliondemons.com` instead in batch.

Now, the best way to run python from batch script is

```
@echo off
python foo.py
pause>nul
```

`pause>nul` will pause the program without `Press any key to continue . . .`, so the console won't just close at the end.

Answer (score 1):

- You need to add a pause to your bat file to see any output of the code.
- Also, Surround your parts of code with Quotation marks whenever there are spaces in command or parameters.

So your bat file content should read.

```
@ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Codes\PROGS\mapIt.py"   
pause
```

Make sure to fix errors (if any) in the Python code.